# How to write js inside window.write()

Tags: javascript, php, html, window.open

This javascript function opens a new window which displays the image that data sais (data contains an image path). I would like to close this new window when the user clicks anywhere on it. I thought i could do it by inserting some javascript inside window.write() but i'm doing something wrong. Any hints?

```
function myFunction(data) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = data;
    window.open(data, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0, width = '+ img.width +', height=' + img.height);
    //window.write(<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).click(function(e) { if (e.button == 0) {window.close(); }}); </script>);
}
```

Comment: There is no `window.write()` method.  There is a `document.write()`, but if you're trying to write into the newly opened window, you'd have to get the document object from that new window.

Comment: Can i get the document object from that new window by doing var mywindow = window.open(....); ?

Comment: Yes, you can get the document object from the new window object.  But, there are timing issues with that and with your code.  For example, you are trying to reference `img.width` before the image has actually finished loading so that won't work.

Comment: Why are you bothering to use a new window to just display an image?  Why not just use an overlay in your current window?  That is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to add JavaScript to a window that only contains an image. Your best bet is to either make an HTML page for each image that does what you want OR open a blank window and add the image and script by manipulating the window's document.

If you go the second route you will need to make a variable for the window:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', '_blank', …);
mywindow.document.…
```